# Gitlab merge rule based on file path

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

How to setup merge rule when diff contains changes from certain file paths, merge request will require approval and reviewer

Use case

- k8s repo contains staging / dev / prod env yaml files
- Any change to file containing /prod/ need mandatory reviewer.

```yaml
 rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      changes:
        - /prod/*
```

Answer (score 0):

[Merge request (MR) approvals](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/approvals/) are not linked to the CI YAML rules. CI rules only control whether a CI job is run.

If you need to require approvals based on changes to specific files, GitLab covers this through the [code owners feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/code_owners.html). Note however that it's a paid feature.

I'm not sure there is a way to do what you want without any paid features, since [required approvals](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/approvals/#required-approvals) is also a paid feature.

GitLab would not prevent the actual merge, but you could use something like the [GitLab triage gem](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/ruby/gems/gitlab-triage) to comment on the merge request who should approve the merge request before it's merged. Similarly, you could use the CI rules to trigger a job that uses the [Notes API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/notes.html#create-new-merge-request-note) to add a comment on the MR.